# Enable reverse debugging in QtCreator for non-gui methods

Tags: c++, debugging, qt-creator, reverse-debugging

I have 2 installations of QtCreator on Windows (with MingW, gcc, g++, make and gdb) and on Ubuntu. On the 2 OS I am able to run some Qt programs (with Qt Windows) or console programs, and debug programs.

But I tried without success the reverse debugging; I checked the option "allow reverse debugging" in the debugger's options and I have a button in the debug view that's called "reverse direction" but when I click on it nothing happens, it does not change other buttons nor transforms the effect of these buttons (from forward to backward).

Comment: Reverse debugging through a GUI message sequence.  Not asking for much, are you?  :)

Comment: Put another way, I suspect that what you seem to expect is sensibly impos.... 'very, very difficult'.  The GUI system a is a complex, message-driven state-machine.  'Going backwards' is going to be err.. 'very very messy indeed'.

Comment: hello, sorry I'm not sure to have well understood you, the reverse debugging works, in java with chronon, or with expensive tools. Or one can try gdb and the console line, but I must confess using qt creator would be a great advantage!

Comment: I would like to specify I want to debug even non GUI projects; anyway even if some future project will involve a GUI part, I will only debug  the non-GUI methods. Was it the meaning of your answers?